# Add filter to comments loop?

Tags: comments

I'm making a plugin which stores referrer data for comments. I already have my database table created, and the data is being stored correctly when a comment is made.

Now I would like to attach a custom div to the comment block for each comment. How would I add a filter to the comment loop? I want to say "if this comment ID has a referrer logged in my table, then print out the referrer in my special div". I can write the function myself, I just need help on where to inject my function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to say what you need to hook into without knowing all the details but I think you may be able to use `comment_text`-- more or less the `the_content` of comments.

```
add_filter(
  'comment_text',
  function ($comment) {
    return $comment.'<div>This is your special division</div>';
  }
);
```

If that isn't quite right, take a look at the [filters listed in the Codex for comments](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference#Comment.2C_Trackback.2C_and_Ping_Filters).

Comment: That sounds perfect. I'll try that next week and let you know. Thanks very much!